# asp.net mvc property changed event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inotifypropertychanged, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm a `.Net` desktop applications developer trying to switch to `ASP.Net` `MVC` (3 or 4 doesn't matter). We have a `.Net` library which notifies any `GUI` you want to put on this `assembly` by `Property Changed Events` (or any other custom event we deemed necessary for that matter).

This might not even be a relevant question, because perhaps it's done totally different in `ASP.Net` `MVC`, but how do you update your `View` in the browser on your client after receiving a `Property Changed Event` from an assembly on your server? We generate these events ourselves by the way. The assemblies are our own.

I've read about `Partial Views`, but I need to look into that. Whatever I came across seemed so cumbersome. Because it's really straight forward and simple in desktop development. So I'm starting to wonder if `Property Changed Events` are the way to go when developing for the web.

Thoughts? Links? Sources? I'm interested.

p.s.: See tags for a further understanding of what I'm going for.

Comment: Look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SIngalR-and-Knockout-based-Real-time-U. You can use signalR for sending data from server to client, and knockout for easy updating properties on your view.

Answer (score 3):

`HTTP` world is entirely different
you request something from the `server(Asp.Net MVC)` and you get a response back from the server.
there is no way in which the server can contact the user back**
 as the asp.net server wouldnt keep anything in memory after the response
so here you are wrong in 2 aspects
1. `property changes` - because after the response there is nothing in the memory of the server there are no `models(Objects)` so there is nothing whoz property is actually changing
2. even if u maintaining something static if that changes there is no way for you to contact the client back
**there are some frameworks available that allow you to contact the client back and they do this by [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: "You are wrong"? Strange thing to say, but I'll ignore that for now.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around the whole client-server architecture, which is difficult for a long time desktop developer. I understand statelessness on one hand. But on the other hand you can put collections of objects in the session for easy access and less roundtrips. One of these objects could give me a notification that I need to update a value in the View. I see that is not the way to go now. This means if you have .NET assemblies which kept state have to be completely rewritten to become stateless for webdevelopment. This is kind of a biggy as you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move away from the Event-driven thinking of desktop (and WebForms for that matter)-development.

MVC is a designpattern for separation of concerns, and no tightly bound events will exist, unless you do some hack-ish work of your own.

You can, however, accomplish this by using frameworks like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) that rely on Javascript and open connections, but the notion of events is not present in MVC.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to move away from desktop and webforms thinking, that's the point of this question. I don't want to do hack-ish work of my own. I want to do what is accepted als the standard for asp.net MVC. Which brings us to SignalR. Is this considered good practice? Or for desktop developers stuck in their ways?

Comment: No SignalR is fine, but I suggest you go through some of the tutorials over at http://www.asp.net/mvc before you throw yourself into the more advanced features. You may find you don't actually need it after all.

Comment: The thing is, we have a lot of .NET assemblies containing our business logic and data access logic. These assemblies kept state. To fully embrace the MVC designprinciples do we need to make these assemblies stateless?

Comment: No, but you should keep in mind that HTTP itself is stateless. So anytime you need to display changes for the client, it has to be pushed from serverside (via. SignalR or similar), or the user has to manually refresh the page.

Comment: First off, thanks for replying still. One more question. You see lots of websites updating content without user input. So I figured the browser can refresh the page (or a part of it) by getting a signal from te server. And that is always done with SignalR? Does it utilize AJAX for this or something?

Comment: SignalR is just one way to do it (although in my experience, the most complete way), and yes, it has some pretty heavyduty AJAX (and similar) techniques at its core. I know that several other websites have implemented their own ways of doing this. You can f.i. achieve a similar result by simply polling the server for new information every x seconds. This is normally done with Javascript.