# Using Observer Pattern in ASP.NET MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have a web project and using ASP.NET MVC.

While inserting a record to the database I am using this method.

View --> Controller --> Service --> Data Layer --> Insert

I want to implement observer pattern to my project in order to send notification to users. For example, if user create a new task for a project, creator of that project should get a notification. Actually, I did it without any pattern but it is hard to maintain.

Let me show my problem in the code

```
public class Project : Entity
{
    private string _name;
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
       if (_name!= value)
       {
          _name= value;
          Notify();
        }
    }
}
```

My notify method should go to the notify service that owned by another project. In order to do that I have to add this project as a reference. But, that project using my model project as reference. I cannot add these two projects as a reference recursivly.

How can I call that notify service from my model?

Comment: You'll have to program against abstractions instead of implementations. Define an interface somewhere where you can reach it.

Comment: This sounds a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/q/12385470/1224069.  Either way, I would think there would be a SignalR tutorial that would show how to do this using an IPropertyNotifyChanged pattern.

Comment: If your controller method is responsible for creating the task and passing it to the Task Service to be saved, why not make the same method responsible for also creating the associated notification and passing it to the Notification Service

Comment: Thanks Stephan. But, I need a centralized approach. If I need to create project in two controller I will add code both of the controllers. I don't want to do that.